# deferred include in make

Tags: makefile, include, deferred

I want to include another makefile after running a particular command because the first command generates that makefile. I tried this

```
debug2:
    cd bench/${BENCH};  verilator --cc top.v
    include ${BENCH_DIR}/Vtop_classes.mk
```

In this case make doesn't recognize the include command and gives an error "make: include: Command not found"

if I try to include without tab then it includes before the previous command is executed and so generates error of no such file

```
debug2:
    cd bench/${BENCH};  verilator --cc top.v
include ${BENCH_DIR}/Vtop_classes.mk
```

Comment: What do you want Make to do *after* building and including `Vtop_classes.mk`? Should it start over from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Add - before : `-include ${BENCH_DIR}/Vtop_classes.mk`

Answer (score 0):

```
INCLUDED-FILES=MakeA MakeB

-include $(INCLUDED-FILES)
# alternatively use sinclude
generate-makefile:
    touch MakeA
    touch MakeB

clean: generate-makefile
    if [ -a MakeA ]; then make clean-A; else echo "No file: MakeA. Run make again."; fi;
    if [ -a MakeB ]; then make clean-B; else echo "No file: MakeB. Run make again."; fi;
```

GNU make will not report errors because of `-include`. When make runs the deferred rules and the included files do not exist the shell prints a message "Run make again". The deferred rules in the example call make a second time, so no error is reported.

Because `-include` does not report errors, `make` can run the generation rule on the first run. The dependencies are resolved for the second run.